# Barcode scanning exclude AVmetadaTypeFace

Tags: ios, barcode, metadatatype

I'm developing a barcode scanner app using AVFoundation. My app successfully captures barcode data but it crash when detect FaceObjectType. How can we exclude this type from being detected to prevent crashing?

I'm using this:

```
captureMetadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [captureMetadataOutput availableMetadataObjectTypes];
```

Comment: how can we avoid the faceObject while scanning for barcode or QR code?

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit late, but I think it will help someone who have the same issue.
For Preventing crash, you need to handle the  AVMetadataObject(https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avmetadataobject), So my suggestion for this is as below (swift 3.0)

```
for metadataObject in metadataObjects {
     if (metadataObject as AnyObject).type == AVMetadataObjectTypeFace {
                return
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will fix the supported object type by using this

```
  NSArray *supportedType =[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                         AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Code,
                         AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Mod43Code,
                         AVMetadataObjectTypeCode93Code,
                         AVMetadataObjectTypeCode128Code,
                         AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN8Code,
                         AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN13Code,
                         AVMetadataObjectTypeAztecCode,
                         AVMetadataObjectTypePDF417Code,
                         AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode, nil];

captureMetadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = supportedType;
```

instead of

```
captureMetadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [captureMetadataOutput availableMetadataObjectTypes];
```

This will help.

Answer (score 0):

See these links, they may help you:

https://www.appcoda.com/barcode-reader-swift/

https://www.appcoda.com/simple-barcode-reader-app-swift/

https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2017/09/building-barcode-and-qr-code-reader-in.html